# How to insert particular excel file fields records into sqlserver database table manually

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel

I am facing some problem with inserting data from excel file to sqlserver database table. kindly suggest me what i need to do?

i.e. i am having bulk copy of data in various excel files. from that excel files, only selected fields of data would be inserted into sqlserver database table.

how can i achieve this functionality manually.
kindly give me reference sites & suggestions.

Thanks in Advance
Satish Chandragiri

Comment: I've retagged this to more appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would connect to the SQL Server DB via VBA from some excel workbook and browse that bulk of Excel files and insert all the data to the DB. The link below shows how to connect to the SQL Server database.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/617788-visual-basic-applications-connect-sql-server.html